# XPath syntax within binding XAML

Tags: xaml, binding, xpath

What is the syntax for using XPath with Binding in XAML? Are there any MSDN pages which describe where to put the braces?

Visual Studio doesn't like the following:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=/One/Two[@id='0']/Three/@Four}" />
```

I want the `Text` of the `TextBlock` to be set to the value of the `Four` attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.xpath.aspx), you should set the binding using nested syntax as follows:

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <Binding XPath="/One/Two[@id='0']/Three/@Four" />
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: I noticed that in the documentation the equals sign and single quotes are escaped when using an inline binding, as in my original example. I will have to try **Text="{Binding XPath=/One/Two[@id\=\'0\']/Three/@Four}"**