# Changing textblock background based on XML data

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

So I have a xml file that holds status for certain helicopters. One part of the xml file holds their weather status. If they're weather status is yellow I would like the binded textblock's background to change to yellow.

I found one answer that did this for a datagrid. Is it the same principle? Sorry for the absence of code, I'm doing this from the mobile application.

Comment: Have you looked into XML Serialization? That might be your best bet. Just create a class called `Helicopter` and give it a property which defines the color. You can then serialize it to an XML file to save the content. And when the app loads, you just deserialize the `Helicopter` object and use the properties how you like.

Comment: @Willam Hodges Yeah. I realized I misread your post. XML Serialization is still an option though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually you would bind the data to a DataTrigger on the Style to format the TextBlock's background. Something like this:

```
<TextBlock Text={Binding Path=TextProperty}>
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Weather}" Value="XXX">
                    <DataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
                    </DataTrigger.Setters>
                </DataTrigger>
           </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

With an XPath Binding you might have to go the full way and write it like:

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <Binding XPath="/Your/Xml/Path" />
    </TextBlock.Text>
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Value="XXX">
                    <DataTrigger.Binding>
                        <Binding XPath="/Path/To/Your/Weather/Property" />
                    </DataTrigger.Binding>
                    <DataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
                    </DataTrigger.Setters>
                </DataTrigger>
           </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: Perfect! So where you stated the Path=Text Property would that still work for xpath?

Comment: It should also work with an XPath see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638247/xpath-syntax-within-binding-xaml). If it doesn't you can still use an XMLSerializer and create a code behind object.